# Get dynamically inserted HTML to work with knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm using JQuery DataTables for all my tables because of all the nice built-in features, but it seems the only way to customize the table layout is to set the "sDom" option attribute for the DataTable and use something like `$("div.SOMECLASS").html(HTML_HERE)` to insert the customized html into the table. (FYI, i'm just trying to customize the header).

The problem is I want the inserted html to use knockoutjs binding. Knockout doesn't seem to initialize the binding this way.

Is there a way to work around this?

This is part of the html that I want to insert. It's pretty much a drop down list of some custom filter functions for the table.

```
'<li><a data-bind="click: Filter(\'Severity 1\', 2)">Severity 1</a></li>'
```

Comment: with Jquery you can use .live or .on to handle dynamic created content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [knockout data-bind on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066732/knockout-data-bind-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You have to call this function after insert dynamic HTML element

`ko.applyBindings(viewModel, elementContainingDynamicContent)`

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/FCN5p/

Comment: This is the correct answer,  I'm not sure why it was so difficult to find. It can't be that uncommon to need to load page content dynamically.   Thanks!

Comment: Note to all, for this to work, use `document.getElementById("elementId")` to get a DOM element; don't use jquery `$('#elementId')`, otherwise, ko raises an error: http://tinyurl.com/laaqf7j

Comment: If you already have the jQuery element, `$element[0]` also works.