# How do I get KnockOutJS to recognize dynamic html with data-bind properties?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an app where I'm dynamically loading content into parts of the page.  Sometimes the code has `data-bind` attributes, which seem to be getting ignored by KnockOutJS.

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="html: code">
    this text is replaced by the JavaScript
</div>
```

```
function AppView() {
    var self = this;

    // This sets the code 
    self.code = ko.observable('<div>this shouldnt show</div>');
    self.stuff = ko.observable('this should show');
}

var app = new AppView();
ko.applyBindings(app);

// Later we override the code.  We're setting an observable, so the app should notice.
app.code('<div data-bind="text: stuff">this shouldnt show either</div>');
```

Esentially, I need the handlers to be initialized.  Do I need to remove all bindings, and reapply?

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJ5tg/)

Comment: Looks like you might have to do applybindings all over again. Check this SO answer for a similar problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066732/knockout-data-bind-on-dynamically-generated-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with knockuot Template binding.

see a working example [here in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MaurizioPiccini/QfLxM/13/)

In your case you have to do something like this:

```
<div data-bind="template: 'myTemplate'>
    this text is replaced by the JavaScript
</div>

<script id="myTemplate" type="text/html">
   <div data-bind="text: stuff">this shouldnt show either</div>
</script>
```

check if it works.

Comment: Thanks.  Sometime between when I asked this an now, I figured out template bindings.  I use them a lot in my current products.  Good answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to remove all binding and reapply.

You can change values in event handlers

```
<div data-bind="html: code>
this text is replaced by the JavaScript
</div>
<span data-bind="click: changeClicked">Change</span>
```

//inside the model

```
 self.changeClicked = function(){
 self.code('<div data-bind="text: stuff">this shouldnt show either</div>');
 }
```

//You can also access from view model with the use of view model instance

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarm/F68Sg/)

Comment: Your fiddle still doesn't give the desired result. Since the OP is inserting a new div, which is data-bound to "stuff", they expect to see `this should show` and not 1this shouldn't show either`