# Dynamically add new div after page load

Tags: knockout.js

On my view I have an option to add users, each `user` is a div with a few fields:

```
<div>
    <input data-bind="value: name" />
    <input data-bind="value: position" />
    <input data-bind="value: email" /></div>
    <button data-bind="click: function(){ $root.addUser()}">SAVE</button>
</div>
```

**This div is being added by a button click, and didn't exist when the page loaded.**

When I try to save the new user by clicking on the SAVE button, it doesn't work, nothing happens, it just ignores my click.

So my question is- how can I make knockout `data-bind` work on dynamically generated element?

I read a few posts online but couldn't find a solution, any help would be appreciated.

`Users.js` script:

```
var User = function (data) {
    this.name= ko.observable(data.name);
    this.position= ko.observable(data.position);
    this.email= ko.observable(data.email);
}
self.users = ko.observableArray([]);
self.addUser= function () {
  console.log("test");   
}
```

And this is the code that adds the div: `Users.ui.js`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.add', function () {
        var strClientSecHtml = "<div class=\"sec\"><div class=\"secIn\">\n...
        $(strClientSecHtml).insertBefore($(this).closest('.sec'));
        showPrimaryLbl();
})
```

Comment: Impossible to know what's going on without seeing your code, but I'm guessing the problem is that your Contacts collection isn't an observableArray.

Comment: @JasonSpake That's not the case. please see my edited question.

Comment: How are you adding the div, through jQuery?

Comment: @JasonSpake Yes.

Comment: This tutorial (http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections) shows you how Knockout work with collections.  You add data to your observable array, and Knockout creates the html to show the content.

Comment: @JoseLuis Thank you I know Knockout well, I'm not asking here about collections, this is a different question.

Comment: Oh, ok, I'm sorry.  :-).  Perhaps this helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066732/knockout-data-bind-on-dynamically-generated-elements.

Comment: It's not a different question. When you use knockout, you do not modify the DOM any other way than via data-binds (both custom and default). You can't brush of @JoseLuis' advice as a "different question": the core of the problem is that you're not using knockout as it is intended which will hurt your project eventually. I'd suggest to follow Jose's advice and look at the tutorial, even though you think you already "know knockout well".

Comment: @user3297291 Thank you for your comment, it is not up to me, this is how the graphic designer did it and I can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a new set of bindings to dynamic content if you create it such that you have an element reference.

```
$('body').on('click', '.add', function () {
        var strClientSecElem = $('<div class=\"sec\"><div class=\"secIn\">\n...');
        $(this).closest('.sec').before(strClientSecElem);
        ko.applyBindings(new User({}), strClientSecElem.get(0)); //get the native element from jQelement
        showPrimaryLbl();
})
```

That being said, with knockout you would normally want to modify your *javascript* objects, and leave DOM modifications up to the library instead of dynamically inserting html. You could push a new User object to the users array, and a `foreach:users` binding would take care of creating the new elements in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried that but I'm getting an error: `strClientSecHtml.get is not a function` any idea?

Comment: @user3378165 There is no "strClientSecHtml" in my example. I changed it to "strClientSecElem" because it was no longer a variable holding html

Comment: Sorry my mistake.

Comment: Working perfectly, thank you so much, I see what you are saying about the normal behavior of KO and I also saw @user3297291's comment, but it's not up to me, this is how the graphic designer did it and I can't do anything about it. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I keep getting an error: `$root.addUser() is not a function` would you know what can causes that? Thanks.

Comment: I managed, instead of `ko.applyBindings(new User({})` i wrote the name of my View Model.

Comment: But now I run into another issue, how can I pass the data filled in the added div to the `addUser()` function on submit?

Answer (score 1):

As Jason so eloquently mentioned, you wouldn't/shouldn't normally do this with knockout. Below is an optimized "knockout-y" version of your code. The `jQuery` code has been converted to a custom binding which will run each time the element has been added.

HTML:

```
<!-- ko template: { name: 'user-tmpl', foreach: users } -->
<!- /ko -->

<script type="text/html" id="user-tmpl">
    <div data-bind="userDivOnLoad">
        <input data-bind="value: name" />
        <input data-bind="value: position" />
        <input data-bind="value: email" /></div>
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.addUser()">SAVE</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

JavaScript Models:

```
var User = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.position = ko.observable();
    self.email = ko.observable();

    if(data)
    {
        self.name(data.name);
        self.position(data.position);
        self.email(data.email);
    }    
}

var AppModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.users = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.addUser= function () {
      console.log("DSA");

      self.users.push(new User());
    }

    //hydrate
    (function(){
        self.users.push(new User());
    }();
};
```

Custom Binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.userDivOnLoad = {
    init: function(element) {
        showPrimaryLbl();
    }
};
```

My recommendation is to remove the DOM manipulation from the binding handler and determine a logical construct in which you can apply it within knockout models.

Comment: Thank you for your anser, I would like to try it, but I think I need more of an explanation, could you?

Comment: I'd be happy to. Can you elaborate on what you'd like explained?

Comment: Thank you, what is the Custom Binding part? What does is do? Where should I place it?

Comment: You can think of custom bindings as "the place where you write the JavaScript/jQuery you used to write all over the place". I usually place them in it's own file, but on small projects in the main.js is also acceptable. Custom bindings, allow you to use the ko binding syntax and inject your own JavaScript logic/bindings. The documentation is here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html