# Anchor data binding inside a td - knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using KnockoutJS for a web application. A table is binded using foreach data binding and table columns are binded using text property. I have a column binding as follows -

```
<td data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="top" data-
bind="html:codesAllopening,attr: {'data-original-title': 
AllOpeningCodeToolTip()}"></td>
```

codesAllopening is created dynamically using below code -

```
self.codesAllopening = ko.computed(function () {
    var codes = self.OpeningCode.Code() + '<a data-bind="click: function() {$root.cancelOpeningCode();}" style="cursor:default;"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a><br/>';

return codes;
}, self);
```

Here, click binding inside codesAllopening is not getting triggered.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data-bind is parsed when you applyBindings so ko will not parse this since its added later.

[knockout data-bind on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066732/knockout-data-bind-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Comment: ok..thank you. I will try to work through the options provided on above link.

Comment: I went through the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066732/knockout-data-bind-on-dynamically-generated-elements) provided above and resolved using `ko.bindingHandlers['html'] = {
  //'init': function() {
  //  return { 'controlsDescendantBindings': true }; // this line prevents parse "injected binding"
  //},
  'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
    // setHtml will unwrap the value if needed
    ko.utils.setHtml(element, valueAccessor());
  }
};`

Answer (score 1):

Any dynamically added HTML with knockout bindings **after** `applyBindings()` is called will not work. In your case, there is no need to use the `html` binding. You can add the anchor and a span to the `td` on load itself:

```
<td data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="top" data- bind="attr: {'data-original-title': AllOpeningCodeToolTip()}">
    <span data-bind="html:$parent.OpeningCode.Code"></span>
    <a data-bind="click: $root.cancelOpeningCode" style="cursor:default;"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a><br/>
</td>
```

There are some good solutions [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066732/knockout-data-bind-on-dynamically-generated-elements) for using custom binding handlers

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But OpneingCode have many codes and I want to have cancel icon for each code separately. Thats why I am trying to put anchor via javascript code.

Comment: @Raj Does the string returned by `OpeningCode.Code()` also have knockout bindings?

Comment: No. It returns plain string.

Comment: @Raj string containing HTML tags or just plain text?

Comment: HTML tags. Actually a </br> tag is added to show list of codes.

Comment: @Raj Then instead of `text` binding, use `html` bindg for the span:  `<span data-bind="html:$parent.OpeningCode.Code"></span>` should work.

Comment: No sir. It doesn't work. My problem is not with displaying the codes but adding the cancel button to each code. In code snippet above, inside self.codesAllopening I am trying to put anchor tag and that tag is working fine if I don't use data-bind but doesn't work with data-bind click/href events.

Comment: @Raj The above code should work. [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1kqypu9t/) to test