# knockoutjs button click event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

I'm building HTML from data which is returned from ajax, it's looking good when I view the source, but for some reason the click event doesn't fire.

This is how I'm creating the markup:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/webservices/WebService.asmx/GetData",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: "{'orderId': " + JSON.stringify(order.OrderId) + "}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data) {
                            if (data.d.length > 1) {
                                $.each(data, function () {
                                    $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                                        var temp2 = "<input type='button' class='btn' data-bind='value: " + v.TeacherId + ", click: $root.downloadImage' />";
                                        $(".downloadButtons").append(temp2);
                                    });
                                });
                                $("#selectOrderPackagePopup").modal("show");
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (n) {
                        alert('Error');
                    }
                });
```

Then I'm able to see the buttons in the modal popup, and this is the generated source:

[image]

The click event is this one:

```
self.downloadImage = function () {
                if (order) {
                    var url = "DownloadImage.aspx?orderId=" + order.id;
                    window.location = url;
                } 
            };
```

I'm not able to fire the click event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get dynamically inserted HTML to work with knockoutjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826482/get-dynamically-inserted-html-to-work-with-knockoutjs)

Comment: Have you solved your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `ko.applyBindings` after you have added the buttons to the DOM. Place it in your ajax success callback, e.g below the `$("#selectOrderPackagePopup").modal("show");` line.